# How to set the type of a variable or function to an std::string?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, c++

I'm using IDA Pro and have identified a function that takes an std::string as an argument.

However when I click on the function and "Set Item Type", entering its definition:

```
std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>,std::__ndk1::allocator<char>> funcname(const std::__ndk1::basic_string<char,std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>,std::__ndk1::allocator<char>>& foo)
```

I get a syntax error:

```
Syntax error near: std::__ndk1::basic_string
```

However there are other variables with this very type that IDA is able to use. Why is it failing when I try to set it?

Comment: From [Ida Help](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1361.shtml): "The function type must be entered as a C declaration.". So it seems that you cannot use C++ classes while setting function type.

Comment: Hmm seems tricky... so that leads to a very different question which is 'how do I deal with a C++ function taking C++ args..'

Comment: Anyway this seems the answer, I will upvote & accept if you post as answer

Answer (score 1):

IDA’s C parser does not handle some C++ syntax like namespaces. There are two options:

1. Rename the local type or struct to have no “wrong” symbols, you can use it in type declaration then
2. Use “Convert to struct*” context menu command on the argument/variable. This bypasses the C parser and sets the type directly.